# Marquee plugin with a div

Tags: jquery, css-animations, marquee

I am trying to use the marquee plugin with a div but i can't figure out how to do it.

If you visit my testing page [here](http://nth.brandonwang.org/stuhf2/) you will see that although there are two slowly moving divs, one to the left, and one to the right, if you continue to wait, they gradually disappear off the page.

I think that using the Marquee plugin, I can fix this but I have no success with this code as the plugin does not seem to be documented very well.

```
$('#lightright').marquee(5);
$('#lightleft').marquee(5);
```

Why does this code not work?

Comment: Plugin url: http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem as answered on your previous question here: [How to make infinite movement of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998771/how-to-make-infinite-movement-of-a-div/998792#998792)